# Why this website does not load on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, opera

My website [quizz.pl](http://quizz.pl/) works fine on FF, Chrome, IE 7-9 (mostly) and Opera.
But in Android browser it displays only background and header. I cannot figure out what is the source of this behavior. Can you please help me? I know this is broad question, but I don't have any clue where to start.

Edit: i've fixed the code with Jukka suggestion and it does not work still in Android and Opera. In Opera especially after second load. Someone here to help?

Comment: Have you tried [debugging it with weinre?](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/)

Comment: On my Galaxy nexus sees ok http://xhiena.net/Screenshot_2012-12-08-00-05-17.png

Comment: @Pointy I dont have VPS nor i dont have Linux so Weinre is not for me.

Comment: @Pablo Thx It's seems to work fine on your dev. On my and on a emulator it does not :(

Comment: @tomaszs I have the latest version of the system (4.2.1)

Comment: Both header and contents loaded on Galaxy S2 running Android 4.03..

Comment: Gunnar Pablo Thanks guys. And now it' works also with fixes suggested by Jukka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from fixing the 102 markup errors reported by http://validator.w3.org

Comment: Ah yes... it was it :) Thx  Simple solution yet successful one :)

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt help as i thought.